# 90s Fantasy novel about girl twin and prince that holds her captive

Tags: story-identification, novel

Honestly, I'm looking for this novel for my mother. She read it a few years ago and has been looking for it again recently.

So the protagonist is a girl whose twin had passed away. The story plays out in a medieval middle-east type setting, with deserts and castles. The girl is captured and held captive by a prince.

Through some turn of events the roles change, the prince is injured and the girl has to look after him.

Finally, plot twist,

> the prince is a girl

Does this sound familiar to anyone? The book was published in the 90s.

Comment: I don't have the book here to check, but could this be "Split Heirs" by  Lawrence Watt-Evans &  Esther M. Friesner?

Comment: No sorry, it's more of a romance than a comedy.

Comment: Are there any fantasy elements to this novel? Sounds like it might be more of a romance or drama with a historical setting.